# Keep process active from PHP

Tags: php, c++, opencv

I have a OpenCV program that I need to contact from PHP script in order to run some face recognition procedures.
So, whenever new image comes to system I have to contact it and send it for processing.

However, what takes longest in my c++ program (OpenCV) is loading a facerecognition model. I.E. it takes ~10sec to load a model and much less than a second to run actual face recognition and return the result.

What I would ideally like is to make c++ program sleep in the background with the model loaded, and wait for signal, in order to process it right away, not waiting for huge file to be loaded.

HowTo? :-)

Comment: You don't keep it active from PHP. You daemonize the program and talk to it using pipes/sockets/whatever.

Comment: Maybe a job server like Gearman (http://gearman.org/) or RabbitMQ (http://www.rabbitmq.com) could help you?